# laravel latest or order by not working from a related table

Tags: laravel

I have my code here. I just want to sort it according to the latest comments posted.

```
$comments = ModelsComment::with('Comments')->where('posts_id', $this->post)
   ->WhereHas('Comments', function ($q){
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');   //->latest()
     })->paginate('5');
```

ModelsComment is my pivot table(no time stamps here)
so i'm trying to sort it by newest comments added(Related table).

However, oldest record is still appearing from the top.
Any help would be appreciated.

My Table structure looks like this

```
POST
id
name
timestamps

ModelsComment(without timestamps)
posts_id
comments_id

Comments
id
name
timestamps
```

I'm trying to query from my ModelsComment, and order the Comments table with the latest/newest entry first.

Comment: Do you want to see the _oldest_ comment at the top, or the _newest_ comment at the top?

Comment: newest comment at the top @TimBiegeleisen . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this version:

```php
$comments = ModelsComment::with(['Comments' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
}])
    ->paginate('5')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ->orderBy('created_at') --> i dont have this column in my ModelsComment

my table looks like this

POST
id
name
timestamps

PostComment(ModelsComment)
Posts_id
comments_id

Comments
id
name
timestamps

I'll edit my post

Comment: @MiaTraxKhalifa you can change `created_at` into `id` or `timestamp`